# wikipedia dump all page titles and pageIDs

Tags: database, wiki, wikipedia, dump

I'm trying to find a wikipedia dump containing pageIds and Titles. I don't want to request it on runtime or request 2000 per request, i want it ALL, i want to make a long list of all the pageIds and titles belonging to them and put them into my own database, so that i can use it in an application that requests the data from my own database.

Anybody know which dumps contain those information? It doesn't matter if they also contain more information that what i need - i can just write an app that picks the info i need.

I did try to request it ... it would have taken 140 days and they put up some limit of 2700 requests ... so it would take forever to get the whole thing, instead i want to download a file dumb and clean the data and upload a file to my own database containing only the info i need

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it myself after getting multiple dumps, in short the answer is: 
enwiki-latest-page.sql.gz

It contains pageids and Titles.

Entries look like this: 
(1217768,0,'Black_River_(South_Carolina)','',0,0,0,0.6285160577990001,'20161001141146','20161001142916',738899573,1654,'wikitext')

First number is pageId. Third entry is title.

Rest i don't know what is - but no matter :D Thanks to myself i solved this issue and will close it :D Big pat on the bag